# Unable to translate "Highest score" related sentences

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, custom-filters, traducir

There are no sentences to translate via [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Highest%20score):

- "Highest score"

> [image: Question filter]

- "Highest scored questions" // from the page `<title>` tag

Comment: Looks like this has since been fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings have appeared (and translated), but for now we are waiting for the next build to see it live.

See related [post on ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11889/176217).